# Measuring the performance of a count query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, count

I'm currently evaluating MongoDB and comparing it to OracleDB. In order to compare them I measure the performance of a dataset in both database environments.

I tried to measure the performance of the count() function in MongoDB but couldn't seem to make it work.

This is what my MongoDB count query looks like at the moment:

```
db.test2.find({"Interpret": "Apashe"}).count();
```

It works fine, but how can I measure the time it took MongoDB to perform this? I tried the usual

```
explain("executionStats")
```

but it doesn't work that way with count it seems.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the expectation here ? Which part of the explain plan is problematic?

Comment: Try using with [db.collection.explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html). Also, see `db.collection.countDocuments`.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite the problem is that adding `explain("executionStats")` to my shown query gives me an error

Comment: @prasad_ thanks, i will try this using countDocuments instead

Comment: Sorry which version of MongoDb are you using? If I try db.collection.explain().count() on MongoDb 4.0.10 I get the result . Anyway the count() without any condition is not good for a comparison because count() does not execute query but reads from metadata. You can see it explained here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Answer (score 0):

count is estimated and comes out of collection stats. Benchmarking it against oracle doesn't seem very useful.

You can try benchmarking countDocuments which should provide a meaningful signal. Though I am also confused why you decided to benchmark counts, a more sensible starting point should be finds and *once you understand how counts are implemented* you can benchmark counts and get some useful signal.

Answer (score 0):

I think according to the documentation here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#mongodb-method-cursor.explain

count() is equivalent to the db.collection.find(query).count() construct. So essentially you can measure the find query.